# Vega-Lite: How do I include image marks in a doughnut chart?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I would like to have image marks surrounding my doughnut chart instead of texts. The example for image marks use x and y for its coordinate. How should I adjust that for a doughnut chart where we work with radius and theta?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4, "image": url},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6, "image": url},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10, "image": url},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3, "image": url},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7, "image": url},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8, "image": url}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 80}
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 90},
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }],
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```

New vega version:

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgTOpIsspoIAASSDTq-ghwsjpyEGgAbEqmSGRwKVi4+EQ4TL6YLghklFBsCAQ46mwAZjQWAPplFRAEAMxFAOwADACcc1MAjGJzBDNIAEy9ABxiU1AbvZtMSDNLcExMUEVQvUjjS+NMK1BLgwAsMzMAHl8zlBwsjIIAAvgo4gkkikALJIADWcAYOGyuXyskKqA+pWQFSq2DwhC6DUoTVMrXanW6fQGcGGuLUE2m80WKzWG22ewORxOZwuVxudweTxeYjen2+f2+gOBYIhIHiiWS6AAYgkyFCoJUlDk8rpMXMceVKuhqoS6iSyS02h0uj1+kMRozJrMFstVustrt9ockMdTudLtdbvdHs9Xu9-lKAUCQaCALrgkC5drKGiykIgehwIJoUD9bzKkC69GFJSYACeOBNIAAjgxEjogjpSP4IEEoPC0Jh1JEk+1BGwspmC4Ii4roeWqzXZB10+F-BYKtDULIGIJBKCkx4K3Bh7Fi-Yu5nK9WUvYoP42AxMHuAEpINMMTE7GZb+XIdTH0Cnmu3n6YP4CRPgab5KCmbBphmP5wABeYgKO45QskU5nugs4IPOghgu+P5QhAvRDggMSgJIbDzmQGp8LeJEgGwKLoBADDEUoiEpCW+r+EgmJZmwQTYQm4KgC4SRsE4tH0SkTEsQhNhjuxaKcUo3EpFAzFgvGrEJDkMRrhuCgzIm8pQOEakeDR6DtBAAAUmwAFQAAoAJJ2dZyiBMxbTMfw7mYJ5HEFAQmwAJQEL5nmYHx4TBVxPEVnKoAmYIZmBDWJiyLZjkuW5HkIF5CA+bllABRiQWheFeWRfxMXKTxPwaTqR7wb+KROv4LjKPQaCbDMSjwDQZBYN1YHJrIqbpiCmYMOo2EjnJRZtUm9VzYWKT1ahNb1o2dCBDQrZKNA4QmqAygdBkejRPwmwKJsRkgEgPw0Jiembko8UrfJ6DxRtKRbXqzZ7dqICHRY8Gncg6YxFdN13Q9T1oC9W4JkoxA2OJmbtj0iII+um6gkAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials and reading through the doc, it seems [Image Mark](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/image.html) cannot be positioned by theta encoding, but the example shows that x and y encodings are supported.

Therefore, I worked out this positioning via simple trigonometry and an extra layer to place the images in the doughnut:

```
{
    "transform": [
        {"joinaggregate": [{"op":"sum", "field": "value", "as": "total"}]},
        {
            "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "cum"}],
            "frame": [null, 0]
        },
        {"calculate": "cos(2*PI*(datum.cum-datum.value/2)/datum.total)", "as": "y"},
        {"calculate": "sin(2*PI*(datum.cum-datum.value/2)/datum.total)", "as": "x"}
    ],
    "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 20, "height": 20},
    "encoding": {
        "url": {"field": "image"},
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [-2, 2]}, "axis": null},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [-2, 2]}, "axis": null}
    }
}
```

[Yet another Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgTOpIsspoIAASSDTq-ghwsjpyEGgAbEqmSGRwKVi4+EQ4TL6YLghklFBsCAQ46mwAZjQWAPplFRAEAMxFAOwADACcc1MAjGJzBDNIAEy9ABxiU1AbvZtMSDNLcExMUEVQvUjjS+NMK1BLgwAsMzMAHl8zlBwsjIIAAvgo4gkkikALJIADWcAYOGyuXyskKqA+pWQFSq2DwhC6DUoTVMrXanW6fQGcGGuLUE2m80WKzWG22ewORxOZwuVxudweTxeYjen2+f2+gOBYIhIHiiWS6AAYgkyFCoJUlDk8rpMXMceVKuhqoS6iSyS02h0uj1+kMRozJrMFstVustrt9ockMdTudLtdbvdHs9Xu9-lKAUCQaCALrgkCYKEQXpsdQIGKgFxJNhObMgNgo9DtBh5fz9bzKhVQ5JKJCYovqVRZBNKXoJHIxWQMQSCBQzRPxpS5drKGiykLJ+BBNCgKuCGu69GFJSYACeOBNIAAjgxEjogjpSP4IEEoPC0CnIkn2oIM-OQIuaxnW-5N9uUrIOpPwv4LAqaFUF7ftQSTDwNzgLJUFiEBkHUK9p0-Hd7Cgfw2AYTBoIAJSQCcGExHYZnA+UEKQ0AUJSbCfkwfwEgIg0SNHWRx0nEFkLgWinxfFJFWhdctx3H8ED-QQwVIyjU3TTNC0kNg-zIDU+GwwtixSCAGCzDsbCXFIV31fxG2otggnEhNwRzSdlHzNSSxATTtOfXTlzRQyGybKAtLBEdny7E1olAgch0skAoHCLyPFU0s2AgAAKTYACoAAUAElEri5RAi0totP4LLMBygyCgITYAEoCAKnLMFM8IyqMpsNzlUBwsESLAh3ExZASlL0sy7KEFyhB8oGyhioxUqKqqwaarM+qPJSH4fJ1ewKOTISUidfwXGUeg0E2GYlHgGgyCwfbmJAMc2AnKdQAYdRxOnXj0C2pMlqelzFo-Db0H3Q86ECGhTyUaBwhNUAbOQScYn4TYFE2RMGx+GhMSCpMmo+6sUiawSv1+g89WPIHtQc1rwZUDoMj0aJYfhxGQCQZHUb7QRwPbEBiBsAtp3PHpETQNHQSAA)

As the order is messed up by the `color` encoding mentioned in comments below, a new `window` transform is added to generate an extra ordering field which is provided to `color` field

[Renewed Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUIHkbOoAnmggKEphEXBoAIwADPlKpkhkOehYuPhESGFB6r609MwMEHDqUHKYcLKYlJ0IBAwEYgAcAMwAbACckwBMowD8EAC8k-kAZMQrACwgAL4KcQlkSanoTP5ZkWhik8XIZWmVeIQEtYH2ja4tbR1dPT6AyGIwmM3mS1W6y2uwORxA8W6pxSaSgV3CN1QBQepXKGGwrxqdS+1B+TFa7U6vUB-TYg2GYymswWyzWm22e0OxyRZzSynR2TQ43GOKeFQJ1XexIapOa5L+VO6vVp9NBTIhrOhHLh3MSKPQOUyGPKAHYdqK8S9JR96t85RT-tTlcCGWDmZC2TDOfDEXrziAAGYCzGjC3PCVvG0kpqMeWUgHOukgxngllQ9mw-YAXUOIB6nWUNFkZDQoHocCCpcDNkE-PQ10NIEwyRweIAjgwkL06IEaKR-BAglAANZoTDqSK5zqCJJVgM1usIk68pTN1tpWR0ovhfwWMqyOuyBiCQT7XMeZLtGKgZDqUchJstvH2NFKNgMbrqABKSELrTQoz5Ge8K3veZZPmk3QAB6YP46i-jQ-6oNMQFKPmbCFsWVbQbBD7zt4i6+siqSrhB6Cbgg26CAcwFlvBsgQAGSQINeICSGw25kGQ6h8N0rFsDgaQQAwLFKPhtZpA2-hIBAkFsEE1HZlyIAuAebBOPxgnoMJonVgRknGtJsnoFAIkHFmYnwQg5TREeJ4KPkOY+uEpkeHxJlsBAAAUcwAFQAAoAJK+V5yiBCJ-QifwYWYBFDYEHMACUBAxRFmDyeEiVGWkqTKfEgiuQkQlFj5AXBaF4UIJFCDRZVlDxUlKV1elClZUoMlpFB5lKKB2FkSAJRPEoLjKPQaBzEUGBwDQZBYONqF5rIBZFiWD4MOo1F4QuaSDTkuZdVt+noF1pHrugHZdjoQQ6P2SjQOE5SgModJIEWMT8HMChzE56RQTQxl2aeSjnKA4mLiRj5nSAF3dtdfaNvdFhVs9yBvag0QfV9P1IH9APHqeZ4WSAxA2BpD6DuobDDuUgNnkAA)

3 changes were made: (2021-07-16)

- Using cos in the `calculate` of y
- Using sin in the `calculate` of x
- Messing up the data value to check if working

[Old & Wrong Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUIHkbOoAnmggKEphEXBoACxKpkhkOehYuPhESGFB6r609MwMEHDqUHKYcLKYlG0IBAwEYgAcAMwAbACcYwBMQwD8EAC8YwAMAGTEi7kgAL4KcQlkSanoTP5ZkWhjBcjFaWV4hARVgfZ1ro3Nre2d3b39g1Gkxm8yWqw2W12+xA8Q6RxSaSg53Cl1QAEYVjciiUMNhHpVqm9qB8mE0Wm0ur8emw+gNhuMprMFst1pttnsDnDjmllMjsmgRli7qU8RVnoTasSGqSvhSOl1qbTAQyQczwWyoZzEgj0DlMiiSgB2IU4h5il41d7SsnfSkK-50oGM0EsiHs6Gw7UnEAAMz5qKGJvuoqeFqJ9UYMvJP3tNIB9OBTLBrMhOwAunsQJ02soaLIyGhQPQ4EFC76bIJeegLnqQJhkjgcQBHBhILp0QI0Uj+CBBKAAazQmHUkUzbUESTLPorVZhh25SnrjbSshpefC-gsxVkVdkDEEgh2mY8yRaMVAyHUg5CdYbOPsSKUbAYHXUACUkLmmmghisj9DL2vIs7zSDoAA9MH8dRPxob9UAmP8lGzNhc3zMtwMgm9p28WdPXhVJFxA9BVwQddBF2f8i2g2QIB9JIEHPEBJDYdcyDIdQ+A6Ri2BwNIIAYBilGwys0hrfwkAgUC2CCcj0w5EAXB3NgnG43j0H4wTyxw0SDXEyT0CgATdjTIToIQEpoj3A8FBWDMPXCQyPC49S8wACmmAAqAAFABJDzXOUQIBJ6AT+ECzBgprAhpgASgIcLgswaTwhivS0lSeT4kERyEkRNgIHc7y-ICoKEBChAwtKygoti+KqqSmTUqUCS0jA4ylEA9CiJAQo7iUFxlHoNBpkxDA4BoMgsGGxCs1kHM8wLG8GHUcisJnNJepyTM2rW7T0Dawjl3QFs2x0IIdG7JRoHCEpQGUGkkDzGJ+GmBRpjs9IwJofSrMPJQTlAYTZwI28jpAE723Orta2uiwy3u5AntQaIXrej6kC+n790PI8TJAYgbBUm9e3UNh+xKX6jyAA)

Comment: The images get out of place when the value is very far apart. What could I adjust to fix this? Putting one value over 100 seems to trigger the misalignment.

Comment: Sorry that I made a mistake in the trigo formulae, adjustments are needed due to true-bearing starting angle

Comment: You don't have to be sorry at all. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out myself. Thank you.

Comment: It is still misaligned for me.

Comment: @Mapring Could you post a link to the Vega Editor showing misaligned chart?

Comment: After some drilling, I found the order in your example is stirred due to the `color` field (seems buggy..). So, there are a few workarounds: 

1) Reorder the data manually such that it is the same as the field used for `color` encoding

2) Reorder the data via `transform` according to the `color` encoding, but I haven't come up with how...

3) Add a `window` transform to generate an extra field for ordering which is provided to the `color` encoding, please refer to the newly added Vega Editor link