# Vega-Lite: Is it possible to have images as labels in a line chart?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to have images as my axis labels. I tried to use the image mark, but that did not work and that is kind of expected. Label expression is also something I tried, but that did not work if I want it to be an image. What else could I tried or is it possible at all?

[Line chart example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVAAPNDsp6xSkyACCikEzQATAAcSjQIZGgghsYEAGaxbA6UOLIRAL4Kjs6uAIzuIJ4AQr7+qGL5YRHo0UgEtAg4yakgGVmoLjpaHpEAwiVoACxdIJWRNQQA7ABeNI0p6QC6GSCCSACecABOdqDImwDWkUxI20pwslBsajTNpiBOd7E0cIJqkShKmGs4cJGybAgbhZfEgHDQbKhZAxBIJlms0KAni83uh-J9vr90ABHBhIWSYOhGGikFppVogTCbPEQBKbBA7EBQCxQaFGTEgfgANhBEIKYJsaQWSj2hzuXx+kTCSDIvyUqg0MEC+XgNDIWCVy3Ol2utzaiOer0iTnREuxuPxhIJJI8-LQUJhcIRICRhvQoPBvnF7JxeIJxitspA0AsmNAagBSBudn0nJ0S2WDE2gidLpRI3CnoxfwBQOTZMFSk21jYghJd2DglDIHh6AgMBOcDe+aAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same technique in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397126/12726294), an image axis can be added via an extra layer:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.5, "img": "data/ffox.png"},
      {"x": 1.5, "y": 1.5, "img": "data/gimp.png"},
      {"x": 2.5, "y": 2.5, "img": "data/7zip.png"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 50, "height": 50},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
      "url": {"field": "img", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }, {
    "transform": [{"calculate": "-.2", "as": "axis"}],
    "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 25, "height": 25},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative", "axis":{"labelExpr": "", "title": null}},
      "y": {"field": "axis", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [0, 2.5]}},
      "url": {"field": "img", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}}
}
```

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAB5oADJTFKAnhatKaCMmhVqkBAGae2JyjlkXAF8FUzQARgcQO1RI6xAnF3RVdQJaBBx-QJAQsNQAJiiYwvjE1xSPAHYALxpMgOCAXRCQQSQbOAAnI1BkToBrNFBMGxw4VyckMnGlAHcaZXo0MXMleBoyLGXzFrhZKDZlGmzNEDNTzxo4QWVXMyURsdcARwYkWUw6NRpSHNshkCXa63dB2B6jcboV7vT7qT6-FoMTqCAFAm4TZyKECPSEgWRsBDHHQ5IK5bGdd4QHydBA9EBQHRQBhtTC4-iUfJYpAGdBIEw0AxBRpKPqDU44jFTGYgeaLGBofLxdabTAKsS7faHY5JPKgNEgs5YiVQt4fL7w6V8gUAtpMa4AURMOG66CNdEEkNkzMEpP+Fyu6N5-IM4KeJph5p+0ugOkhoGUBKQxyMqxKzURyNRAYNZVDuPxhNkxNJQqUnX0bEEv1OMY9AJiIAgMCQ5duJaAA)

===== 2021-07-20 =====

Your BarChart's `x` encoding uses the `x` field which is not evenly distributed, so it is misaligned.

If you do have the `a` field shown in your editor, simplest way is to replace the encoding as `"x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal", "axis": null}`

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVAAPNDsp6xSkyACCikEzQATAAcSjQIZGgghsYEAGaxbA6UOLIRAL4Kjs6uAIzuIJ4AQr7+qGL5YRHo0UgEtAg4yakgGVmoLjpaHpEAwiVoACxdIJWRNQQA7ABeNI0p6QC6GSCCSACecABOdqDImwDWkUxI20pwslBsajTNpiBOd7E0cIJqkShKmGs4cJGybAgbhZfEgHDQbKhZAxBIJlms0KAni83uh-J9vr90ABHBhIWSYOhGGikFppVogTCbPEQBKbBA7EBQCxQaFGTEgfgANhBEJAay8YJsaQWSj2hzuXx+kTCSDIvyUqg0MEC+XgNDIWBVy3Ol2utzaiOer3evkl7LYmz1wI8grQUJhcIRICRxvQ-Nt6Kl2Nx+MJBJJSmgFkxoDUAKQNzs+k5OiWywYm0ETpdKJG4VNGL+AKBSbJwqUm2sbEEJLuQcEIb5kQgMBOcDeeaAA)

Even the `a` field was not there, you may wanna add such a field for aligning, or even ordering, the image axis.

The last resort I can think of is `window` transform which is an overkill, but adds no extra value as well:

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVAAPNDsp6xSkyACCikEzQATAAcSjQIZGgghsYEAGaxbA6UOLIRAL4Kjs6uAIzuIJ4AQr7+qGL5YRHo0UgEtAg4yakgGVmoLjpaHpEAwiVoACxdIJWRNQQA7ABeNI0p6QC6GSCCSACecABOdqDImwDWkUxI20pwslBsajTNpiBOd7E0cIJqkShKmGs4cJGybAgbhZfEgHDQbKhZAxBIJlms0KAni83uh-J9vr90ABHBhIWSYOhGGikFppVogTCbPEQBKbBA7EBQCxQaFGTEgfgANhBEJAay8YJs5NUsjUbGUDLYOEilwY+J5kQcAvBviRr0iACoWgslLEqQhMbYoTCFDoljqQHtDncvj9ImEkGRfkpVBoYIF8vAaGQsB7ludLtdbm1Ec91eglYLfLb2Ti8QTjASSR4o5DoYIlNALJjQGLkDc7C53FpKGIlnCESA1Si+cqbOi7djcfjCUnnSAs4Ic1EAUgC6hbPpOWayUoGJtBJXq-bwtGMX8AUDJ2S0hbNtY2IISXdO934egIDATnA3iugA)

Comment: I could not get it to work with a line chart. Can you have a look at my edited question?

Comment: I have added how to specify the xAxis